# How can I enable Bluetooth on HP Specter x360

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I would like to ask how can I enable the Bluetooth on my HP Specter x360.

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:0074]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:00bb Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
[    7.949020] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    7.949060] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.949065] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.949067] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.949072] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.663565] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.663567] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.663572] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: I don't see BT devices. Is it a dual boot? Is BT enabled in BIOS?

Comment: yes it is dual boot

Comment: Disable Windows fast Start feature.

Comment: To be honest, I do not know if is activated in BIOS

Comment: It is not in BIOS, it is in Windows.

Comment: Please can you tell me what to do. I am lost

Comment: Start Windows and disable Fast Start feature there. If you don't know how to do it, use Google.

Comment: Does BT work on Windows?

Comment: Yes BT works on windows. I saw how to disable on google. Many thanks. I will try to do it now. You think by doing that BT will work on ubuntu?

Comment: I disabled the Fast Start from Windows 10 but I saw the same results

Comment: Then post output of `dmesg | grep -i blue` to the question.

Comment: I posted do you understand anything.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: On settings --> Bluetooth says no BT detected..

Comment: Any command to install BT?

Comment: In general, what are the next steps? Many thanks in advance.